# How can use a function ( if ) on javascript

Tags: javascript, function

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class nothing

{

    public static void  main ( String arge[] )


    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );

        int mork; 
        int mork1;
        int mork2;
        int mork3;


        System.out.print ( " Enter The mork ");
        mork = input.nextInt();

        if (mork > 90 )
        System.out.print("A");

        if ( mork1 > 80)
        System.out.print("B");

        if ( mork2 > 70)
            System.out.print("C");

        if (mork3 >= 60)
            System.out.print("D");

        else System.out.print("H");



    }
```

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript here...

Comment: @user523424: for a guide on asking questions others can answer, read ["Writing the perfect question"](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely JAVA not JavaScript...

[EDIT]

Here is valid way to do a if/else if/else statment in Java, if that's what you're asking...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nothing {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        int mork;
        int mork1; // <--- never used...
        int mork2; // <--- never used...
        int mork3; // <--- never used...

        System.out.print( " Enter the mork " );
        mork = input.nextInt();

        if( mork > 90 ) {
            System.out.print( "A" );
        }else if( mork > 80 ) { // <-- changed mork1 to mork since mork1 is never initialized
            System.out.print( "B" );
        }else if( mork > 70 ) { // <-- changed mork2 to mork since mork2 is never initialized
            System.out.print( "C" );
        }else if( mork >= 60 ) { // <-- changed mork3 to mork since mork3 is never initialized
            System.out.print( "D" );
        }else{
            System.out.print( "H" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And I assume you use all caps to emphasize and not because Java is an acronym (which is not) :P

Comment: That's definitely a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Ok sorry , I don't konw if this JavaScript or Java , But this project Right or wrong. How to make the project properly

Comment: If you don't know what language you're writing, you should find another profession.

Comment: @subhaze: That's much better!  :)